# Subdomain not working with https, but works with http

Tags: ssl, dns, apache2, subdomain, ubuntu-14.04

I have the following problem:

I'm using `letsencrypt` to obtain ssl-certificates for my sites.
Recently I registered a subdomain, which is working fine. Say my subdomain is called `test` and my main site is called `website`, then `https://www.website.com` works, as well as `http://www.website.com` (which redirects to the https-site), as well as `https://website.com`. Now `http://test.website.com` or `test.website.com` works well, but `https://test.website.com` delivers me the main site (so https itself seems to work, but i get the content of the main site, not of the subdomain. Does anybody know what the problem could be? 
I'm using apache2 on Ubuntu14.04

Comment: This is not a general problem but a configuration issue. Since your configuration is unknown it is hard to point out what exactly is wrong.

Comment: Well I used the tutorial from here `http://askubuntu.com/questions/463618/setting-up-subdomain-on-ubuntu-server` to configure the subdomain itself and `letsencrypt` to autoconfigure the ssl-things, I didn't configure anything else

Comment: I still have no idea how your configuration looks like. I does not matter how you created it but it matters what the configuration is.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich And the content of which files do you need to know my config?

Comment: The Apache configuration files, i.e. below /etc/apache2.

Comment: I added these lines to my apache2.conf 
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName subdomain.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/subdomain.mydomain.com
</VirtualHost>

That's all I changed in there

Comment: @SteffenUllrich no idea?

Comment: Since you still did not provide the full configuration there is nothing I could base any idea on.

Answer (score -1):

Just check the certification installed for load balancer or not? 
If this is the problem, Just add this certificate to it and it will resolve the problem.